# В чем отличие такого синтаксиса в rust?

Tags: rust

Правильно ли я понимаю, что только пример c функцией h3 - это динамический диспач, когда первые два - статический? Есть ли принципиальная разница между h1 и h2?

```
fn h1(s: impl AsRef<str>) {
    s.as_ref();
}

fn h2<T: AsRef<str>>(s: T) {
    s.as_ref();
}

fn h3(s: &dyn AsRef<str>) {
    s.as_ref();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> только пример c функцией h3 - это динамический диспач, когда первые два - статический?

Да

> Есть ли принципиальная разница между h1 и h2?

Единственная разница в том, что из-за анонимности типа в `h1` эту функцию нельзя будет вызвать с явным указанием типа в [турборыбе](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html#non-operator-symbols):

```rust
h1::<&str>("a") // error[E0632]: cannot provide explicit generic arguments when `impl Trait` is used in argument position

h2::<&str>("a") // нормально компилируется
```